# Javascript Object declaration creates [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

I am trying to create a javascript code that will download all the data from a certain api, filter it by certain values and return it as objects. But I am having problems with properly declaring an object. Since my output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMNOf.jpg and I cannot access any objects through console. Could anyone help me?

```
function renderHTML(data) {
var htmlString = new Object();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name; "</p>"
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].flag; "</p>"
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].translations.de; "</p>"
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].translations.es; "</p>"
}

countryContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

Comment: Change `var htmlString = new Object();` to `var htmlString = '';`

Comment: Why would you initialise an ***HTML string*** as object?

Comment: That was not the smartest thing to do. I have changed the line as you have sugested. The output seems ok, but I still cannot access the objects in the console. And can htmlString be treated as an object with values name, flag and translations?

Comment: A string is a string. Sounds like you want to create *DOM objects*, e.g. `document.createElement('p')`…

Comment: According on what you seems to want, you should write something like ** var htmlString = data; ** Like this you may access htmlstring by console using htmlString[0], for instance, to access the object

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `htmlString` as an Object and then using string operands on it.

So you must first declare it as a string :

```
var htmlString = '';
```

Also the example code is missing a closing `}`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append strings to an object, that is not possible. You are else trying to concatenate with semicolons, that is wrong as well.
Your code should work like this

```
function renderHTML(data) {
var htmlString = '';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].flag + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].translations.de + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].translations.es + "</p>";
}
}

countryContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

You can use **foreach** as well

```
data.forEach(function(element){
    htmlString += "<p>" + element.name + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + element.flag + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + element.translations.de + "</p>";
    htmlString += "<p>" + element.translations.es + "</p>";
});
```